# How to populate a ListView in NativeScript with JSON Data from a WebService?

Tags: javascript, listview, nativescript, webrequest

I'm using NativeScript + JavaScript. I'm trying to populate a ListView with data JSON-Data from an API. The Web-Request works like it should but I can't manage to add the data i fetch from the server to the ListView. But I'm able to add hard-coded data to the ListView.

Here's the code of my ViewModel:

```
"use strict";
 var config = require ("../../shared/config");
 var observableModule = require("data/observable");
 var observable_array_1 = require("data/observable-array");
 var arrayOfDataItems;

 var ViewModel = (function () {

function ViewModel() {
    this.initDataItems();
}
Object.defineProperty(ViewModel.prototype, "dataItems", {   
    get: function () {
        return this._items;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
ViewModel.prototype.onAddItemClick = function (args) {
    this._items.push(new DataItem("1","Fooo","Bar"));
};

ViewModel.prototype.initDataItems = function (args) {
    this._items = new observable_array_1.ObservableArray();

    //conifg.apiUrl holds the URL where i make the GET Request
    //I can populate the ListView if i write this._items.push(new DataItem("1","Lorem","Ipsum" here
    return fetch(config.apiUrl + "competition")
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();         
    }).then(function(data) {  
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            //I can't populate the ListView here when I get the response from the server              
            this._items.push(new DataItem(data[i].id,data[i].name,"Useless    Description"));
        }
    });
};

return ViewModel;
}());
exports.ViewModel = ViewModel;

var DataItem = (function (_super) {
__extends(DataItem, _super);
function DataItem(id, name, description) {
    _super.call(this);
    this.id = id;
    this.itemName = name;
    this.itemDescription = description;
}
Object.defineProperty(DataItem.prototype, "id", {
    get: function () {
        return this.get("_id");
    },
    set: function (value) {
        this.set("_id", value);
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
Object.defineProperty(DataItem.prototype, "itemName", {
    get: function () {
        return this.get("_itemName");
    },
    set: function (value) {
        this.set("_itemName", value);
    },
    enumerable: true,   
    configurable: true
});
   Object.defineProperty(DataItem.prototype, "itemDescription", {
    get: function () {
        return this.get("_itemDescription");
    },
    set: function (value) {
        this.set("_itemDescription", value);
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
return DataItem;
}(observableModule.Observable));
exports.DataItem = DataItem;
```

This is the code of my Controller

```
var BasePage = require("../../shared/BasePage");
var topmost = require("ui/frame").topmost;




var CompetitionPage = function() {};
CompetitionPage.prototype = new BasePage();
CompetitionPage.prototype.constructor = CompetitionPage;

var viewModel = require("~/views/results/observable-array-model");

CompetitionPage.prototype.onPageLoaded = function(args) {
   var page = args.object;
   page.bindingContext = new viewModel.ViewModel
}

module.exports = new CompetitionPage();
```

And here is the XML of my ListView

```
      <GridLayout loaded="onPageLoaded" orientation="vertical" rows="50, *">
      <StackLayout orientation="vertical" backgroundColor="#f8f8f8">
      <StackLayout row="0" orientation="horizontal" horizontalAlignment="center">
              <Button text="Add" tap="{{onAddItemClick}}" ios:margin="0"/>
              <Button text="Del" tap="{{onRemoveItemClick}}"   ios:margin="10"/>
              <Button text="Update" tap="{{onUpdateItemClick}}" ios:margin="10"/>
              <Button text="Reset" tap="{{onResetClick}}" ios:margin="10"/>
          </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
          <lv:RadListView items="{{ dataItems }}" row="1" id="ls">
              <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
                  <lv:ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical"/>
              </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
              <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                  <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
                      <Label fontSize="20" text="{{ _itemName }}"/>
                      <Label fontSize="14" text="{{ _itemDescription }}"/>
                      <Label fontSize="10" text="{{ _id }}" />
                  </StackLayout>
              </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
          </lv:RadListView>

      </GridLayout>
```

Comment: There is a lot of code there. Can you please follow the guidelines on creating a minimum complete verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I do not see any "web service" request in your code snippets. Can you show us how you are doing that request and how you are mapping the response to be served to the RadListView items property ?

Comment: @VladimirAmiorkov It should work with the Two-Way DataBinding of the ObservableArray I'm creating. When I call onAddItemClick via the Button from the View i can actually add something to the ListView. I commented my code to mark where I make the request to the webservice.

Comment: What do you mean cant, does the collection get updated but the RadListview does not refresh or do you mean something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not passing **the correct** `this` to the `.then` of the fetch operation.

Simply save the current this in a **WeakRef** and use that in the callback:

```
ViewModel.prototype.initDataItems = function (args) {
    this._items = new observable_array_1.ObservableArray();

    var that = new WeakRef(this);

    return fetch(config.apiUrl + "competition")
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();         
    }).then(function(data) {  
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

            that.get()._items.push(new DataItem(data[i].id,data[i].name,"Useless    Description"));
        }
    });
};
```